# Asynchronous file IO in multi-threaded application with variable index

Tags: python, multithreading, io

In one of my programs, I have the following method :

```
def set_part_content(self, part_no, block_no, data):
    with open(self.file_path, "rwb+") as f:
        f.seek(part_no * self.constant1 + block_no * self.constant2)
        f.write(data)
```

I did this this way because of the following :

- I have to write at different index (the reason why the `f.seek` is here)
- and this function is thread safe (thanks to the `with` statement)

My issue is this function is called approximately 10k to 100k times, and obviously it is really really slow (it represent half of the execution time of one of my most critical set of functionality) because of the opening/closing time.

Because of the `f.seek`, I can't open the file directly in the `__init__` function in order to operate on it (if 2 thread use the function at the same time, it result in a bad index for one of this two, which is critical).

Is there any module / way that could accelerate this function ?

Comment: Wait wait wait. What? Since when does the `with` statement magically make code safe for multi-threaded use? Are you sure you don't confuse that with the use of `with` to enter and exit a code block protected by a lock (e.g. `threading.Lock`)? Neither PEP-343 nor the documentation of `with` support your claim and it's news to me as well. What is the source of that claim?

Comment: No, the `with` statement does not make this thread safely. But the I/O file in Python are thread safe.

Comment: Hmmm... It's more the way I am using which is thread safe in fact : 2 thread would never write in the same part of the file simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with python, so I am not sure if `with` statement will make this function thread safe or not.

If it does, you won't have 2 threads using the function at the same time.

If it doesn't, your function is not thread safe. You need a lock to ensure thread safety. You may check [implementing file locks using Python's with statement](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19531). Another option is to make this function async, and let single thread to handle all the writing.

Comment: Yes, files IO in Python using the standard library (`with open(...) as f` or `f = open(...) [...] f.close()` are thread safe. I'm more looking for a "caching file manager" which will allow me to treat asynchronously my I/O, and if I read the file, it will check first if there is any changes ready to be commit before reading the file. Should I implement this myself ?

Comment: Yes, you can implement it with `Queue` easily. If you let the same thread to handle read&write, you don't need to check pending write operations, which simplifies the logic.